# Firebase in flutter getCurrentUser never unwraps the Future and I can't get at the Data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

So I have a Flutter app with Firebase authentication. I have a dart file for sign in and registration and then a separate dart file with different Widgets for a list of data. I want to get the current user so I can get that users personalized data from the database. But for some reason I can never get that user. Here is the code:

```
Future getUser() async {
     final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

     return user.getIdToken();
  }
```

```
     return FutureBuilder(
        future: getUser(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) return Text(snapshot.data);
          else if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("data error (see futurebuilder)");
          return Text("Await for data");
        },
      );
```

But on my debugging device the Text output just says data error (see future builder) which is the error message I wrote. However I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I don't see why this isn't just giving me the user ID token. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the user is signed in your debugging device?

Comment: Fairly certain but I don't know how to tell because it keeps having an error so I can't check to see if it's actually finding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code from `snapshot.hasData` to `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done` and see if this helps you. I have the exact same setup in my app and this works for me.

something like this should work

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: getUser(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
           return
           //Execute code after future is returned 
         } else {
           return CircularProgressIndicator();
         }
        },
      );
```